# No query-parameter types are displayed in the FASTAPI documentation if I use the annotation T | None

Tags: python-3.x, validation, parameters, annotations, fastapi

I write annotations like this for the path operation function in FastAPI:

```
min_price: int | None = None
```

As a result, the OpenAPI documentation is missing an indication of the required variable type:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmCX5.png)
How can I leave the default value None, but make the client understand that the int type is assumed here?

Annotating with Union and Optional yields the same result.

Comment: I'm havin a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. The parameter is an optional int in the documentation, isn't that what you want? Also `int | None`, `Optional[int]` and `Union[int, None]` are the exact same thing in Python, so you SHOULD get the same result with all of them.

Comment: @M.O. I want the documentation to display the desired type of query-parameter (in our case int), but not to lose the functionality that the client can pass nothing at all and then min_price will be None. The documentation does not contain the desired query-parameter type

Comment: Have you tried using pydantic Field? https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/fields/